# How to use only Client_id and Client_secret in OAuth2

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are using OAuth2.0 for security.I have gone through many resources online and everyone is using client_id ,client_secret along with UserName and password.But I only want client_id and client_secret and get the access token without userName and password.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the oauth2 client_credentials flow instead of authorization_code or implicit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595818/1098564 for an example.