# How authorize in Spring OAuth2 by client_id and secret only?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

Now I am using the next configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(mAppConfig.dataSource())
                .withClient("virto")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token");
    }
}
```

It requires to send `client_id, client_secret, username, password`... But I need to provide `access_token` for my trusted servers that has `client_id` and `client_secret` only... How can I make it? Is it possible?

Comment: There are a few flows in OAuth2 such as `password flow` (which requires client_id, client_secret, username and password), `client_credentials` flow which only requires `client_id and client_secret`. You need to research on how to enable `client_credentials` flow in your Spring OAuth application. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534073/spring-boot-oauth2-client-credentials SO post for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to configure a client with client_credentials grant

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(mAppConfig.dataSource())
                .withClient("virto")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials");
    }
}
```

To get a token you send a post request, with credentials as base 64 encoded.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/paymentiq/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials -h 'Authorization: [clientId:secret]'
```