# Set Spring OAuth2 userInfoUri programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37534073/1490322) I can see how to set the Spring OAuth2 client credentials.

But I need to also set the `userInfoUri`.  Typically that is set using the `security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri` property.  But just like the aforementioned SO question, I need to set it from my Java code.

There should be an object I can inject into the Spring context, or Autowire a config object to set the `userInfoUri`.

EDIT:  Below are some related dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @dur the client being configured is used by the resource server to verify the token.

Comment: @dur thanks for the advice about JWT and storing the token.  This is an existing sprawling microservice network.  I am just trying to change how we configure our secrets and credentials across all our services.  Changing to JWT is beyond the scope of what I am working on.

Comment: @dur, trying it out now.  can you post it as an answer.

Comment: @dur, was able to test that out and it didn't work.  it looks like `ClientRegistration` was not intended for resource servers, but instead intended for the clients of the resource servers.... I presume.