# How do you create JDBC TokenStore in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I tried to follow this answer to add JDBC TokenStore to my app.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595818/148844

It is working with an `InMemoryTokenStore`. I need to know where to put this code

```
@Bean(name = "OAuth")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.oauth")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I tried to put it in

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
```

But I got the error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2Configuration': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

So I moved it to the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.example.mapper")
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

But then it gave a different error

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null

So where do I put that snippet to define the bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the database configuration properties in your `application-{profile}.properties`, in particular they need to be prefixed by `datasource.oauth`. Here `profile` will be any of the profiles that your application is running on (e.g: dev, stage, prod).

The error that is showing clearly says that there is no `datasource.oauth.url=..` property in the specific properties file.